# MYSQL >> Decimal in AVG()

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, decimal

I have a couples of dates imported by csv, I made a few options such as: CONVERT (field, DECIMAL (10,2)) and I had no luck, any suggestions?

> > type = TEXT
> >
> > Select field ...
> >
> > Select AVG(field)

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Is "dates imported by csv" a typo as you are then applying decimal and avg functions to it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry for the bad explain, I have a problem with the data, because not have decimal format, I try this and it work fine, 

>> CAST(REPLACE(field,',','.') AS DECIMAL(65,20))

Answer (score 0):

`SET div_precision_increment = 3;` to get 3 decimal places for divides and `AVG()` (and perhaps some more things).